# React Hook "useState" is called conditionally. React Hooks must be called in the exact same order in every component render error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

I am encountering an error after a git merge (I accidently had eslint warnings turned off). However, I don't know what is exactly causing this error, and how I can fix it.
The error is:

> ERROR in [eslint]  src/pages/PageHome.js   Line 47:49:  React Hook
> "useState" is called conditionally. React Hooks must be called in the
> exact same order in every component render  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
>
> Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

```
export default function PageHome() {
      var maxWebshopId = 0;
      const importedWebshopObject = JSON.parse(
        sessionStorage.getItem("client_shops")
      );
      function handleWindowSizeChange() {
        setWidth(window.innerWidth);
      }
      useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener("resize", handleWindowSizeChange);
        return () => {
          window.removeEventListener("resize", handleWindowSizeChange);
        };
      }, []);
    
      PrimeReact.ripple = true;
    
      const [width, setWidth] = useState(window.innerWidth);
      const isMobile = width <= 768;
    
      // Menu fold in/out state
      const [visible, setVisible] = useState(true);
      if (importedWebshopObject.length >= 1) {
        importedWebshopObject.forEach((element) => {
          console.log(element);
          if (parseInt(element.id) > maxWebshopId) {
            maxWebshopId = parseInt(element.id);
          }
        });
    
        const [WebshopOrderId, setWebshopOrderId] = useState(maxWebshopId);
        const value = { WebshopOrderId, setWebshopOrderId };
    
        return(
          <WebshopOrderIdContext.Provider value={value}>
            <div
              className='page-home'
              style={{ backgroundColor: "var(--surface-ground)" }}>
              <DashboardSidebar
                overlay={isMobile}
                visible={[visible, setVisible]}
              />
    
              <Menubar
                className='border-none pr-2 shadow-1 fixed z-5 w-full p-0'
                model={null}
                start={
                  !visible && (
                    <Button
                      icon='pi pi-bars'
                      className='p-button-secondary p-button-text p-3'
                      onClick={(e) => setVisible(true)}
                    />
                  )
                }
                end={
                  <div className='flex flex-row'>
                    <WebshopSwitcher />
                    <Divider className='m-0' layout='vertical' />
                    <LogoutButton />
                    <Divider className='m-0 mr-2' layout='vertical' />
                    <DarkModeButton />
                  </div>
                }
              />
              <div
                id='content-container'
                className='flex flex-row justify-content-center transition-duration-300'
                style={{
                  marginLeft: visible && !isMobile ? "20rem" : "0rem",
                  minHeight: "100vh",
                }}>
                <span className='spaced-container mt-6 w-full p-5'>
                  <Outlet />
                </span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </WebshopOrderIdContext.Provider>
        );
      }
      else {
        return(
          <div className='page-home'>
            <div className='flex flex-column flex-wrap justify-content-start align-items-start'>
              <h1 className='text-3xl font-bold m-6'>
                Je moet minstens één webshop op je account hebben om dit portaal te
                kunnen gebruiken.
              </h1>
              <Button
                label='terug naar de inlogpagina'
                className='p-button-primary p-button-outlined p-3 m-6'
                onClick={() => (window.location.href = "/login")}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Exactly what the error is telling you.  This is inside of an `if` block:

```
const [WebshopOrderId, setWebshopOrderId] = useState(maxWebshopId);
```

React hooks don't allow that.  Each rendering of the component must call the same hooks in the same order.  Move it outside of the `if` block, up to where your other `useState` call is:

```
const [WebshopOrderId, setWebshopOrderId] = useState(maxWebshopId);
const [width, setWidth] = useState(window.innerWidth);
const isMobile = width <= 768;
```

Even if the component will only actually *use* that state based on a condition, the state still needs to *exist* regardless of that condition so the framework can manage it.

Comment: aah yes! I don't know what happened. Tried to do that earlier and created an infinite rerender loop. Now it works, I've probably messed up some brackets before. thanks!

Comment: Keep in mind that the initial state of the hook depends on `maxWebshopId` variable which is updated inside the IF block.